# stopImmediatePropagation on mat-expansion-panel not working after upgrading to Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, events, angular-material, event-propagation

**Problem**
I had a dialog that pops up with a list of expansion panels with children of other expansion panels. This is all using angular material. Prior to upgrading to Angular 9, I ran event.stopImmediatePropagation in the space down event to make sure that when a user is editing a field that is placed inside the unexpanded panel, it would not open the panel on space down. Now, when I try to edit that same field, the expansion panel opens on every space hit and no space is added in the field.

**Expected Outcome**
I want to be able to edit the field nested in the expansion panel using the space bar to add spaces without the panel opening

**Direct Issue**
event.stopImmediatePropagation() and event.stopPropagation() are no longer working and the expansion panel is still opening on space

Code

````
 <mat-accordion 
                                cdkDropList
                                id={{question.id}}
                                [cdkDropListData]="question.answers" 
                                cdkDragLockAxis="y"
                                (cdkDropListDropped)="dropQuestion($event)">
                                <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let answer of question.answers; let k = index" class="panel-box"
                                    cdkDrag
                                    [cdkDragData]="answer"
                                    #answerPanel>
                                    <div class="panel-placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>
<!-- HERE IS THE CODE - IVE ALSO TRIED IMMEDIATEPROPAGATION --> 
                                    <mat-expansion-panel-header  (keydown.Space)="$event.stopPropagation();">
                                        <mat-panel-title>
                                            <input name="placeholder" type="text" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" placeholder="Enter placeholder" [ngModel]="answer.isButton ? answer.displayValue : answer.placeholderText" (ngModelChange)="answer.isButton ? answer.displayValue=$event : answer.placeholderText=$event" class="condition-input">
                                        </mat-panel-title>
                                        <mat-panel-description>
                                            Click to edit this {{returnAnswerType(answer)}}
                                        </mat-panel-description>
                                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                                    <mat-action-row class="action-row">
                                        <div>
                                            <button style="color: #000" class="action-button" mat-mini-fab color="secondary" (click)="moveObject('answer', 1, i, j, k)">
                                                <mat-icon class="action-button-icon" matTooltip="Move Down">arrow_downward</mat-icon></button>
                                            <button style="color: #000" class="action-button" mat-mini-fab color="secondary" (click)="moveObject('answer', -1, i, j, k)">
                                                <mat-icon class="action-button-icon" matTooltip="Move Up">arrow_upward</mat-icon></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <button class="action-button" disableRipple mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="updateForm(false)"><mat-icon class="action-button-icon" matTooltip="Save">save_alt</mat-icon></button>
                                            <button class="action-button" style="color: #000" disableRipple mat-raised-button color="secondary" (click)="openAnswerSettingsDialog(answer, question)"><mat-icon class="action-button-icon" matTooltip="Edit">edit</mat-icon></button>
                                            <button mat-raised-button color="secondary" *ngIf="answer.isCard" style="color: #000;" class="action-button" (click)="openImagePickerDialog(null, answer, 'answer', i, j, k)"><mat-icon class="action-button-icon" matTooltip="Change Icon">add_photo_alternate</mat-icon></button>
                                            <button mat-raised-button color="secondary" style="color: #000;" class="action-button" (click)="openConditionsDialog('answer', answer)"><mat-icon class="action-button-icon" matTooltip="Conditions">shuffle</mat-icon></button>
                                            <button class="action-button" style="color: #000" disableRipple mat-raised-button color="secondary" (click)="addObject('answer', i, j, true, answer)"><mat-icon class="action-button-icon" matTooltip="Duplicate">file_copy</mat-icon></button>
                                            <button class="action-button" disableRipple mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="deleteObject('answer', i, j, k, answer.id)"><mat-icon class="action-button-icon" matTooltip="Delete">delete</mat-icon></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </mat-action-row>
                                </mat-expansion-panel>
                            </mat-accordion> 
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the issue. The event needed to be on the input and not the panel itself ...

Answer (score 0):

<input matInput [(ngModel)]="name"  (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"          (keydown.Space)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation()">

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).